# Can I use a P2 jack to capture audio?

Tags: audio, connector

I'm new to StackExchange.

I would like to know if it is possible to use a P2 connector to capture audio.

I already use it to play audio on headphones but I plan to pick up the audio from a smartphone and play it on a speaker I have.

Is it possible? If so, can you please tell me what could I do to achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Voting to close: Questions on the _use_ of electronic devices are off-topic here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never heard about a "P2" connector and neither does Google. If it is the 1/8" stereo plug used for headphones then it can pickup a stereo signal and feed a stereo amplifier. Two resistors can convert the stereo into mono to feed a single amplifier.

A headphones signal is too weak to feed a speaker without an amplifier.